# How to store values of loop in matrix when 'i' is not a number, but a character?

Tags: r

To put some context to my question, I have a large data set. I would like to analyze the dataset in subsets based on a column variable (which is a character vector). I would then like to store parts of this result in a matrix. I have used loops before to store values calculated from each cycle in a loop into a matrix, but only when 'i' is numeric and not character.

What I have so far is below: 
The main issue is that I use 'i' to identify the position of the matrix I would like to store the values in, but it doesn't work when 'i' is a character.

```
list <- c("xyz","usd","lki","josdl","olid"......"kadl")
output= matrix(ncol=5, nrow=length(unique(c))

for(i in list){
    x <- filter(df, colvar == "i")
    if(nrow(x) <=1) next
    y <- metagen(RR, SE, data=x) #meta-analysis results

  ###### Inputting values from metagen into dataframe ####
      meta.analysis[i,1] = "i" #colvar
      meta.analysis[i,2] = y$TE.fixed #fixed effect model
      meta.analysis[i,3] = y$seTE.fixed #seTE.fixed
      meta.analysis[i,4] = y$lower.fixed #95%CI-lower bound, fixed.effect
      meta.analysis[i,5] = y$upper.fixed #95%CI-upper bound, fixed effect
      meta.analysis[i,6] = y$zval.fixed #Z-value, fixed effect
      meta.analysis[i,7] = y$pval.fixed #P-value of Z-value, fixed effect

      meta.analysis[i,8] = y$TE.random #random effect model
      meta.analysis[i,9] = y$seTE.random #seTE.random
      meta.analysis[i,10] = y$lower.random #95%CI-lower bound, random.effect
      meta.analysis[i,11] = y$upper.random #95%CI-upperbound, random effect
      meta.analysis[i,12] = y$zval.random #Z-value, random effect
      meta.analysis[i,13] = y$pval.random #P-value of Z-value, random effect

      meta.analysis[i,14] = y$k #Number of studies
}
```

Any help/input would be appreciated! =)

Comment: can you use a different iterator like `j`, which you iterate within the loop? `j <- 1; for(i in blah){do stuff; x[j,1] = other stuff; j = j+1}`?

Comment: Also, using `filter(df, colvar == "i")` will literally filter out when the column variable equals the letter `i`, not what value that variable takes.

Comment: That probably explains another problem that I come across... Thank you for putting that out. Would you know any remedies to these problem?
(I suppose I could recode the character values in 'list' as numerical values though that would add an extra step)

Comment: do not surround `i` in quotes. Also, wouldn't you want `nrow(x)` to be greater than 1...I assume `metagen` fits some sort of model?

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.

Actually, I thought 'next' skips that subset if it is less than one. Metagen is a function from a meta-analysis package so I need more than one row to calculate a summary statistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a vectorized approach with `sapply()` as the [metagen](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/meta/docs/metagen) object returns a list of various components:

```
list <- c("xyz","usd","lki","josdl","olid"......"kadl")

meta.analysis <- sapply(list, function(i){
         x <- filter(df, colvar == i)    
         y <- metagen(RR, SEE, data = x)[c("TE.fixed", "seTE.fixed", "lower.fixed",
                                           "upper.fixed", "zval.fixed", "pval.fixed",
                                           "TE.random", "seTE.random", "lower.random", 
                                           "upper.random", "zval.random", "pval.random")]
         y <- c(i, y)   # colvar
         return(y)               
     }
)
```

To ensure a matrix return, consider `vapply()` -however, leave out the *colvar* since it is a character and not numeric and elements in a matrix must be of one type:

```
meta.analysis <- vapply(list, function(i) { ...same as above...}, 
                        FUN.VALUE = numeric(12))
```

Comment: Works and much simpler to use than a loop. Thank you Parfait.

Comment: Awesome. Indeed, this is the vectorized approach and the preferred way in R when running iterations.